# Screen replacement for Nexus 5X

Tags: android, touchscreen

I believe this is on-topic as per https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/266/1 (it's a bigger electronic part). I'm up for debate on it, though.

---

I have a Nexus 5X, and I just broke the screen. This makes me unhappy, and it's not usable.

I've heard that the LED screen is fused to the glass, which might make this harder. That said, I'd still like to attempt a repair before buying a whole new phone.

My requirements:

- Budget of up to $50, but I'm flexible on that. Less is better.
- OEM is best; I'd rather not have some kind of knockoff. I'm flexible on that too.
- Easier to install is ideal, but I'm not afraid of using a screwdriver.

What's the best replacement?

Comment: Plenty, @SiXandSeven8ths. I'd rather not seed this question to steer answers toward/away from any options.

Comment: "I've heard that the LED screen is fused to the glass" does this mean that only the glass is broken? In many cases, even when only the glass is broken (and even when the two parts can be separated), I change the whole thing (glass+LCD) because its easier to replace (pasting the glass onto the LCD without powders is such a pain). Is that what your were thinking about by saying "Easier to install is ideal, but I'm not afraid of using a screwdriver." ?

Comment: @comicurus Only the glass is broken, yes. The display under it is fine - right now I'm using it without issue with just a bunch of shipping tape so I don't cut up my fingers. I'm considering buying [the whole glass+LCD+frame assembly](https://www.phonepartworld.com/lg-nexus-5X-lcd-screen-digitizer-with-frame) - only ~$50, and easier to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying [the whole LCD assembly w/ frame](https://www.phonepartworld.com/lg-nexus-5X-lcd-screen-digitizer-with-frame) **($52)**:

[image: img credit PhonePartWorld]

<sup>Image credit https://www.phonepartworld.com/lg-nexus-5X-lcd-screen-digitizer-with-frame</sup>

- It seems to be OEM; everything fit perfectly and it worked without any fiddling
- It was fairly easy to install; I didn't need to break out a heat gun to remove the front glass itself. The hardest part was removing the back cover, which was done fairly easily with a flathead screwdriver and a credit card.

The only problem I have now is the volume buttons are a little harder than normal, which I suspect is a mistake I made putting it back together. I'll probably tear it apart again to fix that.